Altair chart empty by dropdown when other chart is displayed
I want to have two different charts, where in the first I can choose an artist in a legend and in the second chart I want to have a dropdown, that filters a year. In my database I have artists, sales and years (for published albums). The charts work fine by itself, but if I want to show both with a vertical concatination I get a problem. The first chart works as expected but the second graph is completly empty on selecting a year.
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data
top = pd.DataFrame({
    'Artist': ['Artist1', 'Artist2', 'Artist3', 'Artist1', 'Artist2', 'Artist3'],
    'Sales': [100, 200, 300, 150, 250, 350],
    'Year': ['2020', '2020', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021'],
})

# Selection for the legend
select_artist_legend = alt.selection_point(fields=["Artist"], bind="legend")

# First plot (cumulative sales over years)
line = alt.Chart(top).transform_window(
    cumulative_sales='sum(Sales)',
    sort=[{'field': 'Year'}],
    groupby=['Artist']
).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X("Year:T"),
    alt.Y("cumulative_sales:Q"),
    alt.Color("Artist:N"),
    opacity=alt.condition(select_artist_legend, alt.value(1.0), alt.value(0.1))
).add_params(select_artist_legend)

# Dropdown selection for the year
year_dd = alt.binding_select(options=sorted(top.Year.unique()), name="Year")
year_select = alt.selection_point(fields=["Year"], bind=year_dd, name='year_select')

# Third plot (sales by artist for selected year)
bar = alt.Chart(top).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("Artist:N"),
    alt.Y("Sales:Q"),
    alt.Color("Artist:N")
).add_params(year_select).transform_filter(year_select)

# Combine the charts
combined_chart = line & bar
combined_chart

Note: I'm using VS Code and Python Notebooks
I tried debugging and trying to seperate the two charts more, didn't seem to help. I also tried stacking bar twice instead of stacking line and bar, but there everything works, so stacking by itself didn't seem to be the problem.

When your do alt.X("Year:T") you are converting the year column to a datestring, which means it no longer matches the strings "2020" or "2021". You can see this by including the column as both a nominal and a temporal value in the same chart (or by viewing the Vega spec in the online editor):
top = pd.DataFrame({
    'Artist': ['Artist1', 'Artist2', 'Artist3', 'Artist1', 'Artist2', 'Artist3'],
    'Sales': [100, 200, 300, 150, 250, 350],
    'Year': ['2020', '2020', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021'],
})

alt.Chart(top).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Year:T',
    y='Year:N',
)


You would have to also convert the string you are comparing against to a datestring in the filter transform for it to work. You can do this by changing the transform to .transform_filter("toDate('year_select.Year')"). This is quite difficult to figure out, so if you wish you can open an issue on the Vega-Lite issue tracker to discuss alternatives, but I'm not sure on the top of my head what an alternative syntax would look like.
